# after swiping the table view cell, we need to tap the trash button more than once to get it delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

My problem is after swiping the table view cell, we need to tap the trash button more than once to get it delete.

```
UIView *scrollViewButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - kCatchWidth, 0.0f, kCatchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
 self.scrollViewButtonView = scrollViewButtonView;
 [self.scrollView addSubview:scrollViewButtonView];
```

---

// delete button

```
UIButton *deleteButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *deleteButtonImage =  [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfileList_SwipeLeft_IconDelete.png"];
UIImage *deleteButtonImageResized = [[IDSSharedData getInstance] imageWithImage:deleteButtonImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(14,17)];
deleteButton.frame = CGRectMake(212, 0, 57, 85);
[deleteButton setImage:deleteButtonImageResized forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(userPressedDeleteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:deleteButton];
```

//cell option : delete

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSArray *indexPathsOfSelectedCells = [[self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
[self setEditing:NO animated:YES];
[IDSSharedData getInstance].EditprofilesMode = NO;

[_Container LeaveEditMode];

switch (alertView.tag) {
        //delete multiple profiles alert view
    case 0:
        if (buttonIndex != 0)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    for (long i = [indexPathsOfSelectedCells count] - 1 ; i >= 0; i--) {
                        //get the selected  profile , delete it from the database and delete the profile cell from the table view with animation
                        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPathsOfSelectedCells objectAtIndex:i];
                        IDSProfile *profile = [_profiles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                        DDLogVerbose(@"Delete profile with profileId = %ld" , (long)profile.profileId);
                        [profile remove:profile.profileId];
                        [_profiles removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    }
                });
            });

        }
        break;
    case 1:
    {
        if (buttonIndex != 0)
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    IDSProfile *profile = [_profiles objectAtIndex:_selectedIndexPath.row];
                    DDLogVerbose(@"Delete profile with profileId = %ld" , (long)profile.profileId);
                    [profile remove:profile.profileId];
                    [_profiles removeObjectAtIndex:_selectedIndexPath.row];
                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                });
            });
        }
        break;
    }
}
[self ExitEditMode];}
```

//delegate methods for OverLayViewDelegate

```
- (UIView *)overlayView:(TLOverlayViewProfile *)view didHitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
BOOL shouldInterceptTouches = YES;

CGPoint location = [self.view convertPoint:point fromView:view];
CGRect rect = [self.view convertRect:self.cellDisplayingMenuOptions.frame toView:self.view];

shouldInterceptTouches = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, location);
if (!shouldInterceptTouches)
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:TLSwipeForOptionsCellProfileShouldHideMenuNotification object:self.tableView];

return shouldInterceptTouches?[self.cellDisplayingMenuOptions hitTest:point withEvent:event]:view;}
```

//didShowMenu for cell

```
- (void)cell:(TLSwipeForOptionsCellProfile *)cell didShowMenu:(BOOL)isShowingMenu {
self.cellDisplayingMenuOptions = cell;



[self.tableView setScrollEnabled:!isShowingMenu];
if (isShowingMenu) {
if (!self.overlayView) {
    self.overlayView = [[TLOverlayViewProfile alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    [self.overlayView setDelegate:self];
}

[self.overlayView setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:self.overlayView];

for (id subview in [self.tableView subviews]) {
    if (![subview isEqual:cell] && [subview isKindOfClass:[TLSwipeForOptionsCellProfile class]])
        [subview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}
} else {

[self.overlayView removeFromSuperview];

for (id subview in [self.tableView subviews]) {
    if (![subview isEqual:cell] && [subview isKindOfClass:[TLSwipeForOptionsCellProfile class]])
        [subview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
}}
```

Comment: where is code to delete item?

Comment: added you can check up now. @AjayGabani

Comment: Why do you maintain two queue at the deletion time? Is it necessary to use it?. Please remove it and then try.

Comment: nope didnt worked either. After swiping cell if i wait 1 second buttons are starting activate & working.. so strange.. @AjayGabani

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing these lines of code. Why don't you use apple's default tableview delete like, You have to implement two methods as follow:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

  // your deletion code....

   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

  } else {
    NSLog(@"Unhandled editing style! %d", editingStyle);
 }
}
```

for more details you can refer [this link.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views)

Comment: but that's not what i wanted to ask. when i swipe to left side, a button is opening, but after 1 second that button are responding my touch.